# Ubuntu 16.04 Installation Problem

Tags: boot, bios

When i inserted my Bootable USB to my Dell N4050 Laptop and tried to boot my laptop, `Setup is Missing -Press any key to restart` error occurs. I have no options of secure Boot in BIOS. What could've gone wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the usb drive you are using is bootable ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with one of my usb stick some time back, this is what i did.

1. Install [HP usb disk](http://filehippo.com/download_hp_usb_disk_storage_format_tool/) and format the usb with file system as FAT using this tool.
2. Download and use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a bootable Ubuntu usb.

This should do the trick.